# A5 Double Gatefold mockup

Tags: mockup

Can anyone please point me in the direction of a good mockup PSD of an A5 double gatefold mockup please?

But one where the gatefolds are half the width of an A5 page or at least a mockup where I could adjust the size of the gatefold perhaps?

I am struggling to find anything for my requirements. I have a number of mockups but my gatefolds are smaller in width than the ones I have downloaded. Similar to how hardback book covers have gatefolds to wrap the cover around the book and they tend to be smaller in width by about half than a normal gatefold. Hope this make sense.

Edit*****************

I have been doing a piece of coursework where I have created a cover sleeve for a brochure that has gatefolds so it wraps around the A5 booklet.

The problem is I created the gatefolds of a smaller width than I think most templates come like from perhaps a printers for example. I did create this in Indesign and not Photoshop.

I just wanted to use one of the Free PSD Mockups you can find of an A5 brochure and display a mockup in my presentation. But I have struggle to find a A5 double gatefold mockup and the one I have found has gatefolds that are only slightly smaller than the width of A5 (which is the norm). So, that they obviously fold in the book when it shuts. They do not demonstrate my book that well.

In future, I would have researched this better when creating my design.

I wondered if such a mockup exists that I could adjust the gatefold width. As I have no experience in creating my own PSD mockups and I am running out of time.

Comment: Do you need a mockup? It seems to me you know exactly what you want: width = 74 + 148 + 148 + 74  = 444 mm and height = 210 mm. The resolution should be 300 ppi. That's basically it, BUT you need to ask your print shop for their requirements. They will probably ask for 3 mm "bleed" and the width (444 mm) could be a problem since it's larger than A3. Maybe they have their own templates. BTW: Photoshop isn't the best choice for making print files like this. You should use PS to create/manipulate images and then place them in InDesign where you add the text and vector graphics.

Comment: Hi Wolff. Please see my edited comment above. Many thanks

Comment: By "PSD mockup" I thought you meant a template to help create a folder in Photoshop. But you are talking about a 3D visualization of a folder, right? Sorry, I wasn't familiar with the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly unlikely to find .psd mockups for *custom* configurations. Most ready-to-use mockups are done at standard sizes/folds/die lines.

I suspect you'll have to "roll your own" or learn to edit the existing mockups you have.

You'll waste *a lot* of time looking for something custom. Time which may be better utilized by editing something you already have.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway, didn't think so but thought it was worth a shot at asking. Many thanks